# Selecting multiple entries from two tables using join

Tags: mysql

I want to produce a result which would provide the following result from the databases given below.

```
20  'someVideo'  'Jason Statham, Tom Cruise, Bruce Wills, Anne Hathaway'  'musicDirector'  'Director
```

Please note that the actors are separated with ", ". Thanks in advance

*term_relationships*
**ID  video_id   related_id   type**
1   20        5            actor
1   20        2            actor
1   20        3            actor
1   20        4            actor
1   20        10           music
1   20        11           director

*actors*  
**ID    TITLE**  
2    Tom Cruise
3    Bruce Wills
4    Anne Hathaway
5    Jason Statham

*musics*  
**ID    TITLE**  
10    musicDirector

*directors*  
**ID    TITLE**  
10    Director

*videos*
**ID   TITLE**
20  SomeVideo

Comment: This is not clear. Provide a better explanation. VideoID 25 does not have a reference anywhere - so how do you want to link the records?

Comment: Sorry about that typo, it should've been 20

Comment: still not correct, see your last table

Comment: thanks, just fixed that, sorry again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrea's answer with GROUP_CONCAT function is brilliant and works. However, it should be perfected by also adding a type-filter for actors like this:

```
select tr.video_id, v.title, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(a.title) SEPARATOR ',') actors,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(d.title) SEPARATOR ',') director,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(m.title) SEPARATOR ',') music
FROM term_relationships tr 
  INNER JOIN videos v on v.id = tr.video_id 
  LEFT JOIN actors a on tr.related_id = a.id and tr.type = 'actor'
  LEFT JOIN musics m on tr.related_id = m.id and tr.type = 'music' 
  LEFT JOIN directors d on tr.related_id = d.id and tr.type = 'director' 
WHERE tr.video_id = 20 
GROUP BY tr.video_id;
```

Comment: Good catch. Forgot that one ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To combine the actor names into a comma-separated list, you can use the mysql `GROUP_CONCAT` function. Check if this SQL statement gets you what you want:

```
Select tr.video_id, videos.title AS video, 
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(actors.title) SEPARATOR ',') AS actor_names,  
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(directors.title) SEPARATOR ',') AS director,   
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(musics.title) SEPARATOR ',') AS music 
FROM term_relationships tr inner join videos on videos.id = tr.video_id 
LEFT JOIN actors on tr.related_id = actors.id 
LEFT JOIN musics on tr.related_id = musics.id and tr.type = 'music' 
LEFT JOIN directors on tr.related_id = directors.id and tr.type = 'director' 
WHERE tr.video_id = 20 GROUP BY tr.video_id
```